# Error when trying to make new exception in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception

iam trying to make new exception called HackerAlertException in app/Exception

and this is the code:

```
<?php


namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class HackerAlertException extends Exception
{
    public function report()
    {
        Log::critical('someone tried to hack system today');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'NOT TODAY'
        ]);
    }

}
```

and i made route to test it in web.php:

```
Route::get('/aa', function (){
    if (!auth()->check())
    {
        throw new \App\Exceptions\HackerAlertException();
    }
});
```

when i visit this link to test the exception it gives me error

> (1/1) HackerAlertException
>
> in web.php (line 24)

what is wrong in code ?

Comment: Umm nothing? It's throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code.

use Exception;

use Log;

class HackerAlertException extends Exception{

```
public function report(){

    Log::critical('someone tried to hack system today');

}

public function render(){

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'NOT TODAY'
    ]);

}
```

}

You missed to use Log; in the header